# P2104 Throttle Actuator Control System Forced Idle error, but car runs fine

Tags: obd-ii, throttle, dtc

*2 days ago,* I had to jump start my 2009 Chevrolet Aveo. I suspect I left the interior light on all night which drained the battery. After I started the car, the *engine warning indicator* was on. (It was previously off.)

I thought it could be temporary due to the exhausted battery so I went for a 20 min ride, switched the engine off for a while, and went on another 15 min ride. But, the indicator was still on.

*The next morning,* it was the same: car ran fine, but the engine warning indicator was on.

*Later that day,* the indicator went off.

*After that,* I did an OBD2 scan. (I hadn't had the scanner when the warning indicator was on.) It returned the following error: `P2104 Throttle Actuator Control System Forced Idle`.

If I understand this correctly, it means the engine should be forced to idle or not go above a certain RPM in order to prevent damage. However, my car has been running fine.

1. Could it be just a faulty sensor?
2. If I erase the error code and the issue is still there, will the error show again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double check your code, Mitchell doesn't list a P2104 for the Aveo. This code also seems to be specific to Fords.

Problems with the TAC after jump starts are caused by the initial low battery voltage and the jump start. This is fairly common on electronically controlled throttles.

Since the code cleared by it self you shouldn't have to worry about it. 
Some codes require multiple trips to self clear. Maybe take a look at the throttle plate and if it's dirty clean it with some approved cleaner and a rag. If there were sensor failures you'd be throwing codes for either the Throttle Position Sensor, Accelerator Position Sensor or for throttle motor performance.

I'd suggest charging the battery until you reach a full charge. As well as checking your charging system and checking for draw. If the code does come back and the charging system and battery are working and fully charged you will probably need to replace the TAC or update the PCM depending on which code you have.